# The method search(BoolQueryBuilder) is undefined for the type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-repositories

I just migrate my spring boot from `2.2.4-RELEASE` with `spring-data-elastic-search 3.2.4` to spring boot `2.6.5` with `spring-data-elastic-search 4.3.3`.

My code here
public Iterable findInstallHistoryByApkId(int intervalle, Long apkId) {

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();                  
    LocalDate beginningDate = today.minusDays(intervalle);

    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    query.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(dateName) 
            .gte(beginningDate)  
            .lte(today));
    query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(apkIdName, apkId));
    query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(event, Event.INSTALL));

    return apkHistoryRepo.search(query);
}
```

raises error

> The method search(BoolQueryBuilder) is undefined for the type ApkHistoryRepository

**ApkHistoryRepository** is just a repository, with a classic definition.

```
@Repository
public interface ApkHistoryRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ApkHistory, Long>
```

Before migrating the code works well, so how could i do to correct it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was in 4.0 that the `search(Query)` method was removed (or deprecated and later removed). Repository methods define their queries by their names.

If you have a `Query` and want this executed, use a `ElasticsearchOperations` instance  for that.

Btw, Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.3.x is out of maintenance since November of last year.